# Testing a website in safari without installing safari on your machine

Tags: browser

I was thinking of a situation where in I might need to test my website in safari or netscape or any other browser. 
But the catch here is that I don't have anything else except Chrome and IE and FF. 
Is there any possible way that a website can be tested in a browser without actually having to install the browser.

Comment: Get a virtual machine and install on that. They're free for limited-duration use from many vendors, and completely sufficient to test browser compatibility.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am using this:

http://browsershots.org/

This is good to have a preview with each browser

Comment: Browsershots works for static images, but if you have things like animated drop down menus it's less useful.

Comment: Also, browsershots is not useful for corporate intranet sites that are not on the public web.